# Liens en tant que réponses

Tags: support, answer-quality, deletion

Pendant ces derniers jours, j'ai fourni deux réponses qui ont été ôtées car elles sont basées sur les liens externes. Ainsi, à supposer qu'un lien tranche au complet une question, je voudrais enquêter pour savoir s'il peut être considéré comme une réponse.

Ceci m'apparaît être un précédent : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2827/1995.

D'ailleurs, on alléguerait que cette question, [« encore » et « toujours » sont-ils sémantiquement interchangeables ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/encore-et-toujours-sont-ils-semantiquement-interchangeables), est réglée plus à fond et à plein par les liens suivants. Il paraîtrait que les consulter est plus efficace que les tapoter de nouveau.

http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa021601et.htm
http://www.tolearnfrench.com/exercises/exercise-french-2/exercise-french-33812.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange est un site de questions et réponses. Un lien vers une réponse, ce n'est pas une réponse.

Le lien peut être indisponible temporairement ou définitivement si le site externe disparaît, est réorganisé, est déplacé, est bloqué par un pare-feu, ou a des problèmes techniques. Il n'est pas non plus disponible si quelqu'un fait une copie hors ligne de Stack Exchange.

Une réponse qui ne contient qu'un lien demande des efforts supplémentaires de la part de chaque visiteur. Avec juste le lien, il est impossible de savoir ce qu'on va trouver à l'autre bout.

De plus, il est rare qu'un lien existant réponde exactement à la question. Il faut souvent filtrer ou expliquer un peu plus.

Les [conseils génériques concernant la qualité des réponses](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) mentionnent ceci :

> **Include du contexte avec les liens**
>
> Les liens vers des ressources externes sont encouragés, mais veuillez fournir un contexte suffisant pour que les lecteurs sachent ce qu'est le lien et quelle est sa raison d'être. Citez toujours la partie la plus importante du site cité, au cas où la cible deviendrait temporairement ou définitivement inaccessible.

Si vous trouvez un site externe qui répond parfaitement à la question, de deux choses l'une :

- soit le site autorise la copie, auquel cas vous pouvez en recopier le contenu en indiquant vos sources conformément à la licence du site ;
- soit le site n'autorise pas la copie, auquel cas vous devrez au moins résumer la réponse avec vos propres mots et inclure le lien comme support ou soutien.

On trouvera de nombreuses discussions à ce sujet sur le [site méta principal de Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=link-only), notamment :

- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)
- [*How* link-only does a post need to be before it's link-only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145900/how-link-only-does-a-post-need-to-be-before-its-link-only)