# Quel genre de notice ou d'attribution veut-on voir accompagner la citation ou l'emploi de données provenant du contenu d'un site web ?

Tags: discussion

Si on décidait de citer un extrait du contenu d'un site web, ou d'utiliser les données ou informations qui s'y trouvent, quel genre de notice ou d'attribution devrait-on inclure et comment la présente-t-on sur le site ? L'exemple provient d'un cas présenté dans une autre [question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/694). On a une liste de verbes sous forme de tableau dans une section particulière du site/de l’œuvre qu'on veut utiliser comme point de départ d'une réflexion. La question ne porte pas sur la pertinence d'incorporer ou non tel contenu dans tel contexte mais bien sur le comment. Il y a certaines [prescriptions](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4918) bibliographiques, comportant certains choix selon certaines [écoles](http://guides.bib.umontreal.ca/disciplines/20-Citer-selon-les-normes-de-l-APA?tab=108) etc. La question porte plutôt sur l'application des normes au site lui-même en ce qui a trait aux citations de contenus provenant du web en général.

- Quels éléments veut-on voir inclure dans la notice ; veut-on y voir une adresse (http://..) ou un/des lien(s) ? De manière interne le document génère une table des liens, est-ce que ça a un impact sur le choix des éléments de la notice ? Peut-on donner un exemple ?
- Ensuite préfère-t-on voir apparaître la référence intégrée au bloc de
  citation ou à l'extérieur ; la voir délimitée d'une manière particulière ?
- Enfin peut-on se contenter d'une parenthèse avant de citer et son
  contenu différerait-il de celui de la notice sous la citation ? Y a-t-il une nuance à faire entre la [citation d'idée](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3250) et la citation au sens strict ? Peut-on donner un exemple ?

---

Voici un exemple bien personnel qui peut servir de base aux commentaires au besoin :

> abstenir, adhérer, afférer, affluer, agir, ardre, coïncider, compéter,
>   confirmer, communiquer, confisquer, confluer, convaincre, converger,
>   déférer, déléguer, déterger, différer, divaguer, diverger, émerger,
>   équivaloir, excéder, exceller, expédier, extravaguer, fabriquer,
>   fatiguer, fluer, frire, fringuer, influer, s'insurger, interférer,
>   interroger, intoxiquer, intriguer, messeoir, naviguer, négliger,
>   ordonner, précéder, présider, provoquer, résider, révérer, somnoler,
>   suffoquer, urger, vaquer, violer, zigzaguer.
>
> [ Liste de verbes tirée de [*Les adjectifs verbaux et le participe
>   présent*](http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison32.htm),  §852b, sur le site *Grammaire 'aidenet'* ]

Comment: Peut être une début de réponse dans le centre d'aide [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)